# Duplicity "no module named dropbox" error

Tags: amazon-s3, centos, duplicity

I try to restore my backup from amazon using the following command as example

```
duplicity restore --sign-key '7F73FA36' --encrypt-key '5FD0100F' scp://rich@backup_server//mnt/backups/edge/main
```

and shell returns the following error

```
"Import of duplicity.backends.dpbxbackend Failed: No module named dropbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1466, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1459, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1312, in main"
```

Any advice will greatly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to store backups in Dropbox, i suppose that this can be ignored.

I wondered the same as you, and looked a bit: it seems to me that Duplicity tries to load a Dropbox backend. See in */usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/backends/dpbxbackend.py*, there is a line  *from dropbox import client, rest, session*
As i do not have this Python Dropbox library installed, it can not find it, but does not prevent me to use Duplicity for other backends

Answer (score 1):

You may install dropbox python client by running

```
root@host# pip install dropbox2
```

Comment: or: pip install dropbox